# currvita - change distance from one cvlist to another

Tags: currvita

i have the following problem: i'm using the currVitae package to write my cv.
I want to increase the distance between the singe "position" (the cvlists).
Up to now, i do it manually using \vspace{2ex}.
Is there an option in the currvita package where the distance can be set automatically for all  cvlists?

Below i give an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{charter}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\cvlabelwidth}{4cm}
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\begin{cv}{CV}
\begin{cvlist}{Personal Date}
 \item[Name] Boss
\item[Prename] Hugo
\item[Birthday] 1.1.1111
\end{cvlist}

 % here i want an automated solution %
 \vspace{2ex}

\begin{cvlist}{Working Experience}
\item[08/2013 - heute]Sell sausages  
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}
\item[-] buy sausages
\item[-] make sausages
 \end{itemize} 
\item[04/2013 - 08/2013] Sell Drinks
\begin{itemize}
  \setlength{\parskip}{1pt} 
 \item[-] buy ingredients
 \item[-] shake cocktails   
  \end{itemize}
  \end{cvlist}  
   \end{cv}
  \end{document}
```

Thanks for your help,

Jogi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the spacing at `\endcvlist`; I exaggerated the spacing just to show the effect.

Note that you have to add more than the baselineskip (about 2ex), so `\addvspace{4ex}` should do. This is because `\endcvlist` already adds the `\topsep`, which the package sets to `\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{picins}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\appto\endcvlist{\par\addvspace{20ex}}% <------  fix here!

\begin{document}

\setlength{\cvlabelwidth}{4cm}
%\pagenumbering{gobble}
\pagestyle{empty} % Better!

\begin{cv}{CV}

\begin{cvlist}{Personal Date}
\item[Name] Boss

\item[Prename] Hugo

\item[Birthday] 1.1.1111
\end{cvlist}

\begin{cvlist}{Working Experience}
\item[08/2013 - heute]Sell sausages  
  \begin{itemize}
  \item[-] buy sausages

  \item[-] make sausages
  \end{itemize} 

\item[04/2013 - 08/2013] Sell Drinks
  \begin{itemize}
  \item[-] buy ingredients

  \item[-] shake cocktails   
  \end{itemize}
\end{cvlist}  

\end{cv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey egreg, thanks for the quick reply!! It fully soved my problem. I only need the picins package to add a picture. Why is \pagenumbering{gobble}
less optimal than \pagestyle{empty} ?

Comment: @Jogi Try with `hyperref`